# solve differential equation with iterated parameter

Tags: python, ode

I'm lerning to solve Differential equation using (scipy.integrate.odeint) and (scipy.integrate.ode). I have a simple example:

`dy/dt=f[i]*t`

and f is parameter corresponding to t[i], same like the example in code ; i.e.

`t[0]=0.0, f[0]=0.0`

`t[1]=0.1, f[1]=0.1`

...

`t[10]=1.0, f[1]=1.0`

the manually result should be:

`y=1/2*f[i]*t**2`, because the initial value of y is zero

then, numerical result of y should be
`[0.0, 0.0005, 0.004, 0.0135, 0.032, 0.0625, 0.108, 0.1715, 0.256, 0.3645, 0.5]`. But when i use scipy.integrate.ode, i have got a different result. My question is:
1. Have i used ode wrong? How can i reduce the errors?
2. Can i use odeint or other method to solve this problem?

The code is like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.integrate import ode
import numpy as np

def func(t, y, f):
    return f*t

t=np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, 11)
f=np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, 11)
dt = t[1]-t[0]

sol= np.empty_like(t)
r = ode(func).set_integrator("dopri5")
r.set_initial_value(0, 0).set_f_params(f[0])

# result of ode
for i in xrange(len(t)):
    r.set_f_params(f[i])
    r.integrate(r.t+dt)
    sol[i] = r.y

res=[]
# result of t**3/3
for a in np.linspace(0.0, 1, 11):
    f=(a**3)/3
    print f
    res.append(f)

# result3
res2=[]
for n in range(0, 11):
    dt=0.1
    y= t[n]**3/3 - dt*t[n]**2/4 - dt**2*t[n]/12
    res2.append(y)

pl.plot(sol)
pl.plot(res)  
pl.plot(res2)
pl.show()
```

I have extend this example to 2-dimensional-differential equations:

`du/dt=-u(v-f[i])`

`dv/dt=v(f[i]-u)`

with initial values:  u(0)=v(0)=1. And below is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.integrate import ode
from numpy import array

def func(t, y, f):
    u,v=y
    dotu=-u*(v-f)
    dotv=v*(f-u)
    return array([dotu, dotv])

t=np.linspace(0.0, 10, 11)
f=np.linspace(0.0, 20, 11)

dt = t[1]-t[0]

# result correct
y0=array([1.0, 1.0])
sol= np.empty([11, 2])

sol[0] = array([1.0, 1.0])
r = ode(func).set_integrator("dopri5")
r.set_initial_value(t[0], sol[0]).set_f_params(f[0])

for i in range(len(t)-1):
    r.set_f_params(f[i])
    r.integrate(r.t+dt)
    sol[i+1] = r.y

pl.plot(sol[:,0])
```

But i get a error message:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\odeint test.py", line 26, in <module>
    sol[0] = array([1.0, 1.0])
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

Comment: you could also try http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is closer to integrating y'(t)=t^2, y(0)=0, resulting in y(t)=t^3/3. That you factor t^2 as f*t and hack f into a step function version of t only adds a small perturbation to that.

---

The integral of `t[i]*t` over `t[i]..t[i+1]` is

```
y[i+1]-y[i] = t[i]/2*(t[i+1]^2-t[i]^2) 
= (t[i+1]^3-t[i]^3)/3 - (t[i+1]-t[i])^2*(t[i]+2t[i+1])/6
= (t[i+1]^3-t[i]^3)/3 - dt*(t[i+1]^2-t[i]^2)/4 - dt^2*(t[i+1]-t[i])/12
```

which sums up to about

```
y[n] = t[n]^3/3 - dt*t[n]^2/4 - dt^2*t[n]/12
```

---

### How to get the correct solution

```
sol= np.empty_like(t)
```

set the initial value

```
sol[0] = 0
r = ode(func).set_integrator("dopri5")
```

use the initial point as initial point, both to make explicit that the point at index `0` is fixed and "used up"

```
r.set_initial_value(sol[0],t[0]).set_f_params(f[0])

# result of ode
```

go from point at `t[i]` to point at `t[i+1]`. Ends with `i+1=len(t)` or `i=len(t)-1`

```
for i in xrange(len(t)-1):
    r.set_f_params(f[i])
    r.integrate(r.t+dt)
```

value at `t[i]+dt` is value at `t[i+1]`

```
    sol[i+1] = r.y
```

With these changes the numerical solution coincides with the manually computed solution.

Comment: @ Lutzl as you said, i have used your formula and edded a new calculation in my code, the third result is near t^3/3, but there is little error too. And i want to make sure, am i wrong in using ode in my code, that make the results different? which one is correct one

Comment: I've added and annotated the changes needed to get the values in the array `sol` at the right indices.

Comment: Thanks, i have lerned a lot from your comments. But i am wondering, how could i extend this example to the 2 dimensional odes. I have added a new example for 2-dimensional-ode using intergrate.ode. But i get the error: `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence`

Comment: This is probably because of `sol= np.empty_like(t)`. I used at a similar place `np.empty(shape(t),shape(y0))`. `np.array([ y0 ]*len(t))` also works.